# prove the products of analytic functions are analytic.

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the product of two real analytic functions $f,g$ is still an real analytic function but failed because I don't know how to prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_{n-i})(x-x_0)^n$ is convergent at $x\in U_\delta(x_0)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $x_0=0$, put
$$A_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k, \quad B_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k,\quad c_r:=\sum_{k=0}^r a_{r-k}b_k,\quad C_n:=\sum_{r=0}^n c_r x^r\ .$$
Let $\rho:=\min\{\rho_a,\rho_b\}>0$, where $\rho_a$ and $\rho_b$ are the radii of convergence of the two given series, and assume $|x|<\rho$. Let an $N>0$ be given. Then $A_NB_N-C_N$ contains only terms $a_jb_kx^{j+k}$ where at least one of $j$ and $k$ is $\geq{N\over2}$. It follows that
$$|A_NB_N-C_N|\leq \sum_{j>N/2} |a_jx^j|\ \sum_{k=0}^\infty |b_kx^k|+\sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_jx^j|\ \sum_{k>N/2} |b_kx^k|\ .$$
Here the full sums on the right hand side are bounded, and the $j>N/2$, resp. $k>N/2$ sums converge to $0$ when $N\to\infty$. It follows that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}C_N=\lim_{N\to\infty}A_N\ \lim_{N\to\infty}B_N=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j\ \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k\ ,$$
as desired. In particular the product series converges at the chosen $x$, hence has convergence radius at least $\rho$.